# How does one early return from a function in cmake?

Tags: cmake

How does one early-return from a function in CMake, as in the following example?

```
function do_the_thing(HAS_PROPERTY_A)
    # don't do things that have property A when property A is disabled globally
    if (PROPERTY_A_DISABLED AND HAS_PROPERTY_A)
        # What do you put here to return?
    endif()

    # do things and implement magic
endfunction()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use `return()` (CMake manual page [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/return.html)), which returns from a function if called when in a function.

For example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(returntest)

# note: your function syntax was wrong - the function name goes
# after the parenthesis
function (do_the_thing HAS_PROPERTY_A)

    if (HAS_PROPERTY_A)
        message(STATUS "Early Return")
        return()
    endif()

    message(STATUS "Later Return")
endfunction()


do_the_thing(TRUE)
do_the_thing(FALSE)
```

Results in:

```
$ cmake ../returntest
-- Early Return
-- Later Return
-- Configuring done
...
```

It works outside functions, too: If you call it from an `include()`ed file, it returns to the includer, if you call if from an file via `add_subdirectory()`, it'll return you to the parent file.

Comment: *double facepalm*